# Find email from div without using class name of div which has email

Tags: jquery, html, css, email

I want to find email from below `html` code.Without using `gb_vb` class.You can use class `gb_ob`.I think it is possible using `regex`. But i don't know how to use `regex`.

```
<div class="gb_ob">
    <a class="gb_pb gb_wf gb_rb" aria-label="Change profile picture." href="https://something/u/0/me?tab=mX&amp;authuser=0" target="_blank">
        <div class="gb_sb gbip" title="Profile"></div><span class="gb_ib">Change</span>
    </a>
    <div class="gb_qb">
        <div class="gb_tb gb_ub">Chirag Satapara</div>
        <div class="gb_vb">zzzzxxxx@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="gb_nb">xyz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried below jquery for this.But i am using a `gb_vb` class.

```
$('.gb_ob').find('.gb_vb').text()
```

Help me to find solution for this.

Comment: Show what you tried so far

Comment: If you intend to access emails from Gmail, you should consider using [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) rather than processing DOM for that.

Comment: Why negetive??? what is wrong in this question?? suggest me anything if my question is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this by using `regular expression`

```js
function extractEmails (text)
{
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}

var emailsArr=extractEmails($(".gb_ob").html()); 
console.log(emailsArr.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gb_ob">
    <a class="gb_pb gb_wf gb_rb" aria-label="Change profile picture." href="https://something/u/0/me?tab=mX&amp;authuser=0" target="_blank">
        <div class="gb_sb gbip" title="Profile"></div><span class="gb_ib">Change</span>
    </a>
    <div class="gb_qb">
        <div class="gb_tb gb_ub">Chirag Satapara</div>
        <div class="gb_vb">zzzzxxxx@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="gb_nb">xyz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can check now it return string of emails

Comment: @BharatsingParmar, look this fiddle , https://jsfiddle.net/u61adca7/ , it is work like this in actual scenario, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way...!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var email = $('.gb_ob > div').find('div:odd').text();
  console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gb_ob">
    <a class="gb_pb gb_wf gb_rb" aria-label="Change profile picture." href="https://something/u/0/me?tab=mX&amp;authuser=0" target="_blank">
        <div class="gb_sb gbip" title="Profile"></div><span class="gb_ib">Change</span>
    </a>
    <div class="gb_qb">
        <div class="gb_tb gb_ub">Chirag Satapara</div>
        <div class="gb_vb">zzzzxxxx@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="gb_nb">xyz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do i know given result is email or not ?? using regex??

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign an id to the email's `div` and just use the id selector.

```
<div id="email" class="gb_vb">zzzzxxxx@gmail.com</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email").call();
});
```